# Java Remove redundant html tags

Tags: java, html

Say have I have html like these

```
<b><b>hello</b></b>
<b><i>hello</i></b>
<b><b><i><b>hello</b></i></b></b>
<b><u><b><i><u><i>hello</i></u></i></b></u></b>
```

How do I remove/merge redundant tags so the output can look like these

```
<b>hello</b>
<b><i>hello</i></b>
<b><i>hello</i></b>
<b><u><i>hello</i></u></b>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/) your code can look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<b><b>hello</b></b>\r\n" + "<b><i>hello</i></b>\r\n"
            + "<b><b><i><b>hello</b></i></b></b>\r\n"
            + "<b><u><b><i><u><i>hello</i></u></i></b></u></b>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

    System.out.println("before: ");
    System.out.println(doc.body());

    for (Element el : doc.getAllElements()) {
        if (hasSameTypeAncestor(el)) {
            el.unwrap();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("========");
    System.out.println("after:");
    System.out.println(doc.body());

}

private static Set<String> tagsIDontWantToNest = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("b","i","u"));

private static boolean hasSameTypeAncestor(Element element) {

    Tag tag = element.tag();
    //handle only these tags: <b> <i> <u>
    if (tagsIDontWantToNest.contains(tag.getName())) {
        for (Element el : element.parents()) {
            if (el.tag().equals(tag)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
before: 
<body>
 <b><b>hello</b></b> 
 <b><i>hello</i></b> 
 <b><b><i><b>hello</b></i></b></b> 
 <b><u><b><i><u><i>hello</i></u></i></b></u></b>
</body>
========
after:
<body>
 <b>hello</b> 
 <b><i>hello</i></b> 
 <b><i>hello</i></b> 
 <b><u><i>hello</i></u></b>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this in java would be to use the String.replace API to truncate the extra HTML tag.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "<b><b>hello</b></b>";
    String[] tagsToRemove = { "b", "i" }; // Extend this to include more tags to remove

    for (String tagToRemove : tagsToRemove) {
        line = delRedundantTags(line, tagToRemove);
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}

private static String delRedundantTags(String html, String tag) {
    String headTagPattern = "<" + tag + ">";
    String endTagPattern = "</" + tag + ">";
    return html.replace(headTagPattern + headTagPattern, headTagPattern). /*Remove the front tag*/
                replace(endTagPattern + endTagPattern, endTagPattern);
}
```

Trouble with this approach is that you need to know what are the redundant tags, for instance the above code would only work for the Bold and italic tags to remove more redundant ones then you will have to extend the tagsToRemove array.

Note: if there are spaces between the redundant tags then the API will not work. In such case you will have to use the trim() API or look into regular expression.

Comment: That doesn't work for <b><b><i><b>hello</b></i></b></b> and <b><u><b><i><u><i>hello</i></u></i></b></u></b>

Comment: woops sorry i didn't notice the other requirements.

For such case then @Pshemo's solution is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This should be generic way to replace duplicate tags

```
     String line = "<b><b>hello</b></b>";
     line = line.replaceAll("<(.*?)><\\1>", "<$1>");
     System.out.println(line);
```

prints

```
<b>hello</b>
```